# Why does github change author of commits after mirroring the repo?

Tags: git, github

I've been working on a project for the past months, and periodically pushing the code to my Github Enterprise account for backups. It is now the end of the project and I wanted to mirror the repo to my personal Github account to use it as part of my portfolio. Since I wanted to keep commit history, I followed [Github recommendations](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/creating-and-managing-repositories/duplicating-a-repository). I.e. I created a new repo on my personal account and then did:

```bash
git clone --bare https://github.com/EXAMPLE-USER/OLD-REPOSITORY.git
cd OLD-REPOSITORY.git
git push --mirror https://github.com/EXAMPLE-USER/NEW-REPOSITORY.git
```

However, the author of the commits has changed in the process. While ALL commits are correctly showing up with my Enterprise username on the Github Enterprise repo, it is not the case on the new duplicate repo. Most commits show up with my personal Github username, and some with the name `Ubuntu`. Explicitly, I noticed that all commits made from my laptop (on which I use using Github Desktop, which is linked to my personal Github account) are now showing up with my personal Github username, and all commits made from remote machines (thus commits from command line) now show as `Ubuntu`, which is the default username of the linux machines I used.

Thus it seems that when duplicating the repo to my personal Github, the author of the commits were somehow changed to "the closest probable author but not the original Enterprise account".

I am a bit concerned about this behavior and did not find any informations online. In this case it does not really matters because both Github accounts belong to me and show my name, but any explanations would be very appreciated.

Comment: Is the author of the commit in the new repo linking to your personal Github account, or does it just show a name without a link? Also, have you added the same email ID both to your enterprise account and your personal account?

Comment: A clone or push or mirror should never actually modify a commit. If you inspect the commit themselves from a clone of your new repo, you should see they have the same sha1 and the exact author info. The only thing that can have changed is *how* GitHub is showing that same information. If it has your work e-mail address as a secondary e-mail address on your personal account, for example, it might decide those two e-mail addresses belong to the same user. My commits show with my own avatar when I use any of the e-mail addresses associated with my github account, for example.

Comment: After all this, I have a question: where and how do you see this change in author, exactly?

Comment: I just added my work email to my personal account and now all commits are showing  up with my personal github username. And I checked the email used for commit on my laptop with `git config --global user.email` and this email was already on my personal AND Enterprise accounts. On the remote machines the email was set to my work email. So it is indeed only a matter of *how* Github is showing information and some email shenanigans from my end. Thanks for the help!